# Ctools 7.x-1.9 update breaking ajax entity lookup

Tags: ajax, entities, chaos-tool-suite

I am having an issue with ajax entity lookup, i upgraded Ctools to the latest 7.x-1.9 and i now have an issue searching for articles in the entity reference autocomplete field, it seems the ajax entity lookup is broken on autocomplete creating space encoding %2520 instead of %20. I am using the Entity Reference Module ver 7.x-1.1 & Entity Api ver 7.x-1.6. Has anyone experienced this? Could it be related to the issue as described here https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.39-release-notes but seems its for Entity Reference Autocomplete & Entityqueue and a bit different to my situation?